# How to export database to another host which doesn't allow to create a new database with my old database name?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, hosting, host

I want to create a copy of my site on another host. I'm under free plan on both the hosts.

The new host in which i'm trying to copy my site allows to create a new database with a name `xyzhost_id_*` only. But my previous database name is `abchostid_*`

There are 40+ tables in my abchostid_* database.

What shall i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you perform a mysqldump there is usually no database information there, just table schema. If the options to create the database are there just open your sql file and remove them. They will look something like "create database your_database" and "use your_database". Then, using phpmyadmin you can simply create the new database and load your SQL file.

Comment: `mysqldump -u root -p --opt [abchostid_*] > [abchostid_*].sql` is this the command? @Dotcomsuperstar

Comment: Just to be clear, is the naming restriction on the table name or database name? Either way, "mysqldump YOUR_DB_NAME -u root -p > dump.sql" will work. You could then use "sed" (linux search and replace) on the file to rename all the tables (if the restriction is on tables names) but that could mess things up if you get the regex wrong. Since it is only 40 tables I would just edit the dump and manually rename the tables making sure you update any foreign keys (aka CONSTRAINT)

Comment: Also, on the new host if you don't have phpmyadmin, first create the database using using something like "create database my_db" and load it with: mysql YOUR_DB_NAME -u root -p < dump.sql

Comment: I think the restriction is on database name only. In this case, what shall i do after dump.sql file creation? Please explain step-by-step. @Dotcomsuperstar

Comment: I have phpmyadmin on both host. @Dotcomsuperstar

Comment: Since you are using phpmyadmin forget mysqldump. Look for an export link in phpmyadmin. There is an option when exporting to rename the database (even tables if you had to). Save the file from your dump and on the new phpmyadmin look for an import link upload your file.

Comment: `mysqldump MY_DB_NAME -u root -p > dump.sql` gave this error: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'mysqldump MY_DB_NAME -u root -p > dump.sql' at line 1

Comment: Don't use mysql dump or any command line stuff. Just open phpmyadmin and do everything there.

Comment: In old host's Export tab> Output:> Save output to a file... File name template: `@SERVER@` can i replace it with my new host's db name? @Dotcomsuperstar

Comment: I don't have access to the phpmyadmin version your host is running so I could not say 100%. The @SERVER@ does not look like it is what you want. If there is not an obvious "Rename Database" option just export the database with no options and try importing in the new phpmyadmin which hopefully has an option to specify the new database name.

Comment: i replaced it my new host's db name and clicked 'Go'. The file downloaded with new host's db name. Now will Import option from new host work with this file? @Dotcomsuperstar

Comment: Imported successfully. :) Now i'm uploading other files to the new host. I'll knock you again if anything goes wrong. :D @Dotcomsuperstar

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can treat "xyzhost_id_" and "abchostid_" as table prefixes. Go ahead and rename your tables and make sure that your scripts will have the new prefix in queries.

Comment: Create a new table on xyz host with abc host's dbname ? Please elaborate. @valicu2000

Comment: You could export each table in separate .sql file and then import them on the new host. Also you need to rename your old database variabile in the script.

Comment: Problem solved. Anyways, for knowledge purpose, i would like to know your method too. Do you mean that i should open each table and modify db name?